# Difference between ACE.sln and ACE_wrappers.sln within ACE_wrappers?

Tags: c++, wrapper, ace

ACE = Adaptive Communication Environment
Download Source: http://download.dre.vanderbilt.edu/
When downloading ACE 6.4.0, there are the following VS solution files under 'ACE_WRAPPERS':

```
    ACE_vc12.sln
    ACE_vc14.sln
    ACE_wrappers_vc12.sln
    ALE_wrappers_vc14.sln
```

- I get why there are separate vc12 and vc14 solutions, but why are there separate solutions for 'ACE' and 'ACE_wrappers'?
- Could these solutions be combined? If so, are they separate for usability for unfamiliar developers? If not, why?
- I use 'ACE.sln' to build ACE. When would I need 'ACE_wrappers.sln'? Examples are appreciated. I'm assuming ACE_wrapper.sln exists so that I can build upon it to meet/simplify needs of my software, making ACE and mySoftware compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ACE_wrappers_*.sln` file contain all projects within ACE (including all examples and tests), the `ACE_*.sln` files only the ACE core library and the gperf utility. At the moment you use ACE and aren't interested in the examples/tests just use the `ACE_*.sln` ones.

Comment: I agree with your 2nd sentence and ignored 'ACE_wrappers_*.sln'. I only needed to use `ACE_*.sln` However, isn't the gperf utility apart of the `ACE_wrappers_*.sln` instead of `ACE_*.sln`? I thought there was a separate `tests_*.sln` for building tests, so that you can use the Perl script provided for testing (all within \ACE_wrappers\tests\)? What is gperf btw? (simply put)

Comment: gperf is a perfect hash generator, just have a look at it when you are interested to learn more